# HTTP Interceptor doesn't logout users when API response is 401

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have implemented Angular HTTP interceptor, the problem i'm facing is when invalidating the token and click on any component of the navbar, my service returns 401 from API gateway...that's supposed to log out the user, however, the HTTP status logs are like: { type: 0 }, and the session remains in localstorage, so user must delete it and try to login again, can you share some insight what could be missing from my approach and how to catch error 401 from services response in my Angular 5 application.Here is my implementation:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injector, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

@Injectable()

export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
refreshTokenInProgress = false;

tokenRefreshedSource = new Subject();
tokenRefreshed$ = this.tokenRefreshedSource.asObservable();

constructor(
private injector: Injector,
private router: Router,
private authService: AuthenticationService
) { }

addAuthHeader(request) {
console.log('add auth header');
const authHeader = this.authService.getAccessToken();
if (authHeader) {
return request.clone({
setHeaders: {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authHeader
}
});
}
return request;
}

refreshToken() {
if (this.refreshTokenInProgress) {
return new Observable(observer => {
this.tokenRefreshed$.subscribe(() => {
observer.next();
observer.complete();
});
});
} else {
return this.authService.refresh()
.do(() => {
console.log('this has been treated');
this.refreshTokenInProgress = false;
this.tokenRefreshedSource.next();
});
// }
}
}
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
this.authService = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);


// Handle request
request = this.addAuthHeader(request);

// Handle response
return next.handle(request).do((data) => {

console.log('HANDLE RESPONSE', data);

return this.refreshToken()
.do((token) => {
request = this.addAuthHeader(request);
return next.handle(request);
})
.catch(() => {
this.authService.logout();
console.log('observable', Observable.empty());
return Observable.empty();
});
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another interceptor for that

```
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { tap } from "rxjs/internal/operators";

@Injectable()
export class UnAuthorizedInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(tap(() => { },
      (err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if ((err.status === 401) || (err.status === 403)) {
            // do whatever you wants here 
            // clear localstorage ...
            // redirect to login page
          } else {
            return;
          }
        }
      }));
  }
}
```

And add `{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: UnAuthorizedInterceptor, multi: true }` as a provider in app.module.ts file